# Shall I ignore this exception from user

Tags: android

Just got a crash report with exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.ads.internal.c$a.run(SourceFile:128)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it ok to ignore this exception as one off.

Comment: What else do you know about the exception? All I can grasp from this is that something a user does can cause a null pointer, and that's not the sort of bug you generally want to leave lying around

Comment: yes, in particular if there is no crash visible to the user. this comes from google ads, possibly not entirely the fault of your app. just make sure it doesn't break anything and the user doesn't see it.

Comment: Might be worth looking into why a null pointer occured and if it can happen again. And then look at handling it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this thread[1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/L7zEbqTilis%20thread) Eric L, developer at AdMob, seems to recognize the crash as a bug in their SW.